# Bounds of heap-allocated memory using malloc.c

Tags: c, linux, malloc, glibc

I am doing some hacking with Doug Lea's malloc.c (under Linux x86_64), and I need to find the lowest allocated address and the address of the high end of the highest allocated chunk--in other words, the bounds of allocated memory--which of course excludes the mspace's struct malloc_state bookkeeping structure.  How can I get these addresses?  Note that I am not looking for the bounds of the entire heap, but only those of the allocated portion, which will usually include unallocated "holes" between the lowest and highest allocated chunks.  I have been using the least_addr and top fields of the malloc_state structure.  Is this correct?  Thank you!

Comment: What do you do with regions that are allocated via mmap?

Comment: In my case, I am not worried about those, because I am mmap-ing a large swath of memory at initialization and then using Doug Lea's create_mspace_with_base with mspace_track_large_chunks, and then mspace_malloc for each call to malloc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, this should work. Malloc uses these values to define where it can allocate memory.

Here is a malloc implementation, it may help answer your questions.

http://asf.atmel.no/avr32/services/storage/mem_manager/dlmalloc/examples/example1/at32uc3a0512_evk1105/doc/html/a00036_source.html

Comment: Thanks!  I already have Doug Lea's malloc.c, which is what that link goes to.  BTW, any idea why least_addr would have a value _lower_ than the address of the mspace itself?  I was expecting that the malloc_state structure would take up the first sizeof(struct malloc_state) bytes of the mspace, so least_addr should come right after that, but my testing shows a least_addr value lower than the pointer address of the mspace.